# How can I access previously set fields in a seam @Observer method?

Tags: events, seam

My current setup is JBoss Seam 2.2 on JBoss 4.2.3.GA.

I have two Beans like so:

```
@Name("mailingManager")
@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)
public class MailingMgr {
  private Mailing selectedMailing;

  @Observer("mailing.letter.success")
  public void recordSuccess(final Object arg) {
    if (null != selectedMailing) { // store arg }
  }

  public void send() {
    selectedMailing = new Mailing();
    if ('EMAIL' == determineType()) {
      EmailSender mailer = (EmailSender) Component.getInstance(EmailSender.class);
      mailer.send(getAddresses());
    }
    // ... more options
  }
}

@Name("emailSender")
@Scope(ScopeType.PAGE)
public class EmailSender {
  public void send(final Set<String> addresses) {
    for (String addr : addresses) {
      // ... create a mail
      Events.instance().raiseEvent("mailing.letter.success", getGeneratedMail());
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when `recordSuccess()` is called `selectedMailing` is always `null`.

As a workaround I'm setting `selectedMailing` in the conversation context manually before calling any code that could potentially trigger my events, and then annotate my field with `@In(required=false)` to inject it again before `recordSuccess` is called. But is there a more elegant solution (keeping the decoupling intact)? And why isn't the calling bean reused to handle the event?

Comment: Curiously enough, if I upgrade MailingMgr's scope to CONVERSATION the whole thing works even w/o the additional manual outjection. But why?